# Created an object with dynamic key value pairs but accessing shows undefined

Tags: javascript, object, fetch

I have an api from where I am trying to put the data into an object so that I can access it in another function.

So my function code is as follows:

```
function getData(){
  const CAT_API_URL = 'https://cat-api-bjoerge.sanity-io1.now.sh/cats'
 let someObj={};
 fetch(CAT_API_URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
       .then(catBreeds => catBreeds.map(cat => {
          someObj["breed"] = cat.breed
         }))
  return someObj;
 
}
```

I then try to get this data into another function

```
function another(){
   let items={};
   items= getData();
   console.log(items["breed"]); // shows undefined
}
```

Here, when I  just console log items it shows the items but when I try to access items.breed I get undefined.

I realise that this error is because of how JS works but I cannot understand the semantics of how it works or how to resolve this problem.
Help regarding how to access this object would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to `return` res.json() from your getData method.

Comment: have one more line in `getData` function.. have that line as `return someObj`

Comment: It's in the promise right?

Comment: @TheBombSquad oh i forgot to add it here but yes i do have that line as well

Comment: ok.. @MariumAli can you send an example of what `catBreeds` would be? i have a feeling that `catbreeds[someIndex].breed` is undefined

Comment: {
"breed": "Abyssinian",
"country": "Ethiopia",
"origin": "Natural",
"body type": "Oriental",
"coat": "Short",
"pattern": "Ticked"
},

Comment: This is one of the objects in catBreeds, like this there are multiple objects so when i map through them and access cat.Breeds and console log it simply i get the desired result